# K means clustering with survey data

Tags: r, k-means, likert

I have a dataset obtained from a survey, where all questions are likert-type, but with different scales (1-5 or 1-2).
Is it possible to run k means clustering if I rescale all to 1-6?

Additional questions:
Would it make more sense to run PCA first and apply clustering to the PCs?

Comment: The thread I marked as a duplicate of your question seems to answer it very well. Your question boils to "do I need to scale the data for clustering" and in many cases, the answer would be "yes", as described in the thread.

Comment: Yes, I understand that rescaling is important. What I cannot figure out is if it makes sense for likert data. Maybe using PCA first would be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, you can scale such data. You can even scale binary values. Scaling is about having the same properties like min & max or mean & sd for numerical reasons.